# Отладка в Visual Studio 2010 и Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Здравствуйте, возник 1 вопрос насчёт отладки в VS2010 именно в Windows 7.
Когда у меня стояла Vista, достаточно было всего лишь нажать F5 (отладка) и все. Любые изменения в коде при отладке сразу же были видны при запуске. Но когда я поставил 7-ку отладка там почему-то происходит по-другому. В начале надо постоянно нажимать F6 (построить решение) и только потом можно уже запускать программу и любые изменения, которые я вношу в код, не отображаются до тех пор, пока решение не будет перестроено. Можно ли как-то это исправить и не перестраивать решение перед каждым запуском?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Правой кнопкой по любой панели вверху->Customise->Keyboard и выберите в списке Keyboard map версию Visual C++ 6.0.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, но, правда, не совсем так: в общем есть вкладка Сервис->Импорт и экспорт параметров, дальше сбрасываем настройки и выбираем в пункте параметры разработки Visual C++ 6.0 (а то я изначально выбирал Visual C#)